# Public static functions in AS 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm coding a small flash game, and wan't to access different functions between classes. In C# I'm used to just making it static, but I'm having some problems with it.

Here goes:

Main.as

```
package  
{
import Bus;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public function Main() 
    {
        addBus();
    }
}
}
```

Bus.as

```
package  
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Bus extends Sprite
{
    public function Bus() 
    {
    }

    private static function addBus()
    {   
        var bus:Bus = new Bus();

        bus.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        bus.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        addChild(bus);
    }
}
}
```

Why can't I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems. 
First: to call a static method, you must refer to the class.

```
Bus.addBus();
```

This allows flash to know you are referring to the static method of the Bus Class, and not a method called "addBus()" in the Main class.

Second, in your Bus.addBus() method you refer to non-static variables. This can cause problems. In particular, you reference the stage object, which will be null because there is no static stage. Instead, you will need to either pass in a reference to the stage, or you could return a new bus from the function and let the calling class add it tot he display list in the appropriate way.

I would recommend the second approach.

As an aside, you may have further plans for the addBus() static method. But i would point out you could easily accomplish that very functionality through the constructor like so:

```
package  
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Bus extends Sprite
{
    public function Bus(stageReference:Stage) 
    {

        this.x = stageReference.stageWidth / 2;
        this.y = stageReference.stageHeight / 2;

        stageReference.addChild(bus); // This is kind of bad form. Better to let the parent do the adding.
    }
}
}
```

=====================================================

## Edits in response to comment

In actionscript, static methods are the exception, not the rule. So to create a Bus, you would change your code as follows. The comments explain the code.

```
package  
{
import Bus;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public function Main() 
    {
        // Add a new member variable to the Main class. 
        var bus:Bus = new Bus();
        // we can call methods of our Bus object.
        // This imaginary method would tell the bus to drive for 100 pixels.
        bus.drive(100);
        // We would add the bus to the display list here
        this.addChild(bus);
        // Assuming we have access to the stage we position the bus at the center.
        if(stage != null){
                bus.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
                bus.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is how you create an instance of your class and access it without the need for any static methods. The "new" keyword is effectively a shortcut to call the constructor method of a class and it returns the new instance of the class. The parent that calls "new" has that instance as a child and has access to calling all of its public methods, and properties.

Comment: I'm not sure about how calling the function in Main.as. Would you then just do Bus.addBus(?). Furthermore I can't access the function if I don't make it static? The main idea was that I could do the whole function in Bus.as and then just call it in Main.as as showed (Bus.addBus();)

Answer (score 0):

Your static function in the Bus class is set to private.  If you make it public, it should work fine.

EDIT:  I dont think that was the answer you were looking for.  Your static function knows nothing about the instance of the class that it is in.  You can't call addChild() within a static function because it doesn't know what to assign it to.  You need to pass the instance of your Main class or stage to the addBus function.

For example:

```
public static function addBus(mainObj) {
    //do your stuff here 
    mainObj.addChild(bus);
}
```

Then your main function would call addBus(this)

Answer (score 0):

Also I believe you need to add `Bus.addBus()` to you main function but it has been a while since I have done AS3 programming